# Представление больших чисел в консоли и на форме

Tags: java, intellij-idea, biginteger, bigdecimal

Если я задаю BigDecimal т.е. возможность в настройках IDEA выводить в консоли большие числа с переводом строки после определённого количества знаков. Допустим по 100 знаков в строке, или необходимо это реализовывать в коде программы?

Comment: это необходимо это реализовывать в коде программы

Comment: а как. если в строку перевести и добавить \n или есть методы какие у больших чисел

Comment: перевести в строку => разбить на части по 100 знаков => после каждой части выставить \n => склеить все в одну строку => вывести в out

Comment: а есть метод для разбиения строки на подстроки одинаковой длины. что-то я несколько способов перепробовал что в нете нашёл но ничего не подходит

Comment: напишите свой метод, он не будет очень сложный

Comment: У вас два вопроса в одном. Не нужно так делать. Если вам нужна инспекция кода, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках консоли IDEA есть опиция при включении которой длинные строки будут переноситься

[image]

Можно так ещё:

```
  private static void printLongString(String text) {
    int STRING_MAX_LENGTH = 60;
    while (text.length() != 0) {
      int endPosition = Math.min(STRING_MAX_LENGTH, text.length());
      System.out.println(text.substring(0, endPosition));
      text = text.substring(endPosition);
    }
  }
```

Comment: переносит если только стоит знак препинания или пробел. число сплошняковое не затрагивает перенос

Comment: Да, вы правы. Тогда без своей функции не обойтись.